# $http.get seems not to have the right headers

Tags: angularjs, get, http-headers

I have a few issues using the get http verb, maybe you can help me.
If I had to guess, I'd say that the headers are bad, but I don't even know how to read the response I have on Firebug.

Extra: javascript file and the response from the server.

Controller.js

```
"use strict"


angular.module('app.controller', [])
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    })
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://www.perdu.com/")
            .success(function (data, status) {
                console.log("Status ;" + status + "; \n" + data);
                $scope.htmlResponse = data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                console.log("connection to google:", status);
                $scope.htmlResponse = status;
            });

});



GET http://www.perdu.com/

200 OK      214ms   

Headers
```

Response

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes

Cache-Control   max-age=0, no-cache

Content-Encoding    gzip

Content-Length  163

Content-Type    text/html

Date    Fri, 11 Oct 2013 15:12:53 GMT

Proxy-Connection    keep-alive

Server  Apache

Vary    Accept-Encoding

Via 1.0 serv320v.numenservices.fr:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE21), 1.0 

cevpx001.multipap.corp:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE21)

X-Cache MISS from serv320v.numenservices.fr, MISS from cevpx001.multipap.corp

X-Cache-Lookup  MISS from serv320v.numenservices.fr:3128, MISS from 

cevpx001.multipap.corp:3128

X-Mod-Pagespeed 1.1.23.1-2169

Request

Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate

Accept-Language fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

Host    www.perdu.com
Origin  http://localhost:8000

Referer http://localhost:8000/app/index.html

User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0

connection to google: 0
```

EDIT: $scope.htmlResponse = 0, but the browser tells me that the requests sent a OK status.

Comment: You need to read up on CORS.

Comment: @DavinTryon yeah, sorry, this wasn't clear. The console logged "Status response : 0". The reason is this was a cross-domain request, and I can't use $http.get for this.

Comment: @moderndegree Yep this was the reason.